# Set table name and column name dynamically in SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am new to C#. I have to get inputs from windows form and execute a sql statement. Here I have to get the table name and column name from user inputs.
I wrote a code like this.

```
string ment = String.Format("update {0} set {1} ='" + radioButton1.Text + "' where RoomId='" + textBox8.Text + "'", textBox7.Text, comboBox1.SelectedItem); 
cmd = new SqlCommand(ment, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This gives an exception.

> It says "Incorrect syntax near '-'".

Any idea on what I missed?

Comment: What is your `ment` looks like when you debug your code? What is your `RoomId` column type? What are your values? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And your `comboBox1.SelectedItem` should be `comboBox1.SelectedItem.Text` in my opinion.

Comment: It has no option as combobox1.SelectedItem.Text

Comment: `comboBox1.SelectedItem` and `comboBox1.Text` should both be fine. But it's a bit hard to tell what's wrong with the syntax if we don't know what the query looks like. :)

Comment: @waka, i printed ment, it says, 
update Monday set T_8-9='Open' where RoomId='W002'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name or column name might have inproper characters. Wrap them in with character ` in MySQL or brackets in MSSQL.

MSSQL version.

```
string ment = String.Format("update [{0}] set [{1}] ='" + radioButton1.Text + "' where RoomId='" + textBox8.Text + "'", textBox7.Text, comboBox1.SelectedItem); 
cmd = new SqlCommand(ment, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

MySQL version.

```
string ment = String.Format("update `{0}` set `{1}` ='" + radioButton1.Text + "' where RoomId='" + textBox8.Text + "'", textBox7.Text, comboBox1.SelectedItem); 
cmd = new SqlCommand(ment, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this thread is old but the correct answer above from @han is sql injection prone..

You can use QuoteIndetifier, here is an example

```
 StringBuilder SQLtext = new StringBuilder();
            SqlCommandBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder();
            string MyColumn = sqlBuilder.QuoteIdentifier(Radio_range.SelectedValue);
            SQLtext.AppendLine(" With ctemp as( ");
            SQLtext.AppendLine(" select convert(varchar(10),sysDate,102) sysDate,convert(varchar(10),WeekDate,102) WeekDate,[Month],[Quarter],[Year] ");
            SQLtext.AppendLine(" from sysCalendar ");
            SQLtext.AppendLine(" where sysdate<=(select max(nominal_date) from ATTENDANCE_AGENT_T) ");
            SQLtext.AppendLine(" and sysDate>=dateadd(MONTH,-12,getdate()) ");
            SQLtext.AppendLine(" ) ");
            SQLtext.AppendFormat(" select distinct {0} as mydate from ctemp order by {1}  desc ", MyColumn, MyColumn);
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIGNAConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLtext.ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mydate", Radio_range.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    DropDownList_Date.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DropDownList_Date.DataTextField = "mydate";
                    DropDownList_Date.DataValueField = "mydate";
                    DropDownList_Date.DataBind();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
```